# Client Side Decorations - How to remove padding between close button and corner?

Tags: gnome3, cinnamon, gtk3, window-decorations

I'm using Debian stable (8.2 as of now), with cinnamon desktop environment.

Some gtk3 gnome apps like `gedit` , `nautilus` have their own window decorations (client side decorations).

The most annoying issue I feel about client side decorations is I cannot blindly corner click on the top right corner to close the window. The extreme top right corner doesn't focus on the close button. There is considerable padding between the close button and the corner which creates this issue.

So, How can I remove the space between the close button and top right corner, So that, when I blindly click on the extreme top right corner it should focus on the close button and close the window.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy workaround for this: just install the [CobiBird](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/CobiBird?content=157985) theme from Gnome-Look.org.